# Minikube NodeUnderDiskPressure issue

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm constantly running into `NodeUnderDiskPressure` in my pods that are running in Minikube. Using `minikube ssh` to see `df -h`, I'm using 50% max on all of my mounts. In fact, one is 50% and the other 5 are <10%.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          7.3G  503M  6.8G   7% /
devtmpfs        7.3G     0  7.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.4G  9.2M  7.4G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        17G  7.5G  7.8G  50% /mnt/sda1
$ df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs           1.9M  4.1K  1.9M    1% /
devtmpfs         1.9M   324  1.9M    1% /dev
tmpfs            1.9M     1  1.9M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1.9M   657  1.9M    1% /run
tmpfs            1.9M    14  1.9M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        9.3M  757K  8.6M    8% /mnt/sda1
```

The probably usually just goes away after 1-5 minutes. Strangely, restarting Minikube doesn't seem to speed up this process. I've tried removing all evicted pods but, again, disk usage doesn't actually look very high.

The docker images I'm using are just under 2GB and I'm trying to spin up just a few of them, so that should still leave me with plenty of headroom.

Here's some `kubectl describe` output:

```
$ kubectl describe po/consumer-lag-reporter-3832025036-wlfnt
Name:           consumer-lag-reporter-3832025036-wlfnt
Namespace:      default
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=consumer-lag-reporter
                pod-template-hash=3832025036
                tier=monitor
                type=monitor
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"consumer-lag-reporter-3832025036","uid":"342b0f72-9d12-11e8-a735...
Status:         Pending
IP:
Created By:     ReplicaSet/consumer-lag-reporter-3832025036
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/consumer-lag-reporter-3832025036
Containers:
  consumer-lag-reporter:
    Image:  avery-image:latest
    Port:   <none>
    Command:
      /bin/bash
      -c
    Args:
      newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py lag_reporter_runner --settings-module project.settings
    Environment Variables from:
      local-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-sjprm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  default-token-sjprm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-sjprm
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  15s (x7 over 46s)  default-scheduler  No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: NodeUnderDiskPressure (1).
```

Is this a bug? Anything else I can do to debug this?

Comment: Could you please provide the result of the execution `kubectl describe pod <yourpodname>` command?

Comment: Updated. It took about 100 seconds for the disk pressure issue to go away on its own

Comment: @sg can you also show an output of `df -i` in the time when you have `disk pressure` issue? There are only several signals which can cause that Scheduling events (nodefs.available, nodefs.inodesFree, imagefs.available, or imagefs.inodesFree) and if it is not a free space, it can be inodes.

Comment: Updated with the inode information, not even close to high usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried:

1. Cleaning up evicted pods (with `kubectl get pods -a`)
2. Cleaning up unused images
   (with `minikube ssh` + `docker images`)
3. Cleaning up all non-running containers (with
   `minikube ssh` + `docker ps -a`)

The disk usage remained low as shown in my question. I simply recreated a minikube cluster and used the `--disk-size` flag and this solved my problem. The key thing to note is that *even though `df` showed that I was barely using any disk*, it helped to make the disk even bigger.